# Makefile installing python module out of of pythonpath?

Tags: debian, python, make, packaging, automake

I'm currently building a project that imply sources from different languages such as C, C++ and some homemade python module.
I'm using Automake/Autotools to install the sources. Problem here is when i'm building a .deb out of this i have some problems.

- Installation

Python installation is performed like this in my Makefile.am

```
$(PYTHON) setup.py install \
    --prefix $(DESTDIR)$(prefix) \
    --record $(DESTDIR)$(sysconfdir)/nina/nina_installed_files.txt \
    --verbose
```

Which is working perfectly when running `make install` (installation path : `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`)

But, when i'm packaging the .deb with `dpkg-buildpackage` commands, it's installing package at `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-package` which is not in pythonpath. I saw that you can append some path to python path, but i don't want to change `.bashrc` if it's not absolutely necessary.

Ideadly i'd like to find a way to install python module at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` but `python setup.py install` doesn't allow full installation path argument.

**PS** :  i alrealy tried `--root $(DESTDIR)` argument instead of --prefix, but this way is installing in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. And install some files in `/usr/local` is contrary to .deb packaging rules. Plus it doesn't work with autotools this way.

Comment: Where is `setup.py` comming from, can you post the code?

Comment: setup.py is the install program of a python module that i've made myself. It aims to wraps some C functions to make them avaiable for another python program.

this is the code
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
# define the extension module
uinput_wrapping_module = Extension('uinput_wrapping_module', sources=['uinput_wrapping_module.c','write_keyboard.c','timed_keystrokes.c','manage_devices.c'])
# run the setup
setup(ext_modules=[uinput_wrapping_module],
    name='name',
    version=1,
    description='Wrapped C',
    url='',
)`

Comment: this might help http://xahlee.info/python/python_whats_pip_easyinstall_setuptools.html

Answer (score 0):

## Update:

It seems that it's depending on the distribution, whether modules are located in `dist-packages` or `site-packages`.

I found this [post in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages) which might help.

**debian**

```
python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
```

returns

```
[(..),'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', (..)]
```

Packages are installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

**centOS**

.. returns

```
[(..), '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Packages are installed in both directories.

Comment: That would be true on another distro than Debian, but when i print my full pythonpath :

 ~$ python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']

No trace of /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
....

Comment: ...
This post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages tells that if I install things from sources it should use site-packages but, it's not even in pythonpath.

(I'm on debian stretch, if it has its importance.)

Comment: You're right, when i'm installing manually the module with
`sudo python setup.py install --prefix=/usr` it's installing in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and python still can't find it.
I'm lost here, why python is installing things where it cannot find it ?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: I know that this problem is only present on Debian like distributions, it's the only one that separates dist-packages and site-packages.